# What filename extensions open in Excel on Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv

If I save a text file on Windows as "foo.csv", it shows up with an Excel-style icon (with an "a," on it), and if I double-click it, it opens in Excel.  This is really handy!

Unfortunately, it doesn't do this for "foo.tsv".

Are there any other extensions for text files which cause a file to get the Excel icon, and open in Excel when double-clicked?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: It's really handy, *unless* the file has nothing to do with Excel, and you'd like to open it with something else. Similarly, opening .doc files with Microsoft Word is really handy unless the file is nothing to do with Word, then it's a nuisance.

Comment: Sure, lack of creator codes is always a nuisance.  But given that Excel's native file format is so incredibly complex, it's nice to be able to make an "Excel" file easily.

Comment: Ken, I'm not sure what you mean by 'creator codes'

Comment: pavium: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creator_code -- a way for the OS to distinguish between the orthogonal concepts of "what type the file is" and "what app it should open with".  Windows has no such concept, so if Excel claims CSV, it claims *all* CSV files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the default file types for excel by:

**XP and below**: you can open an explorer window, click tools, folder options, and, finally, click the "file types" tab.

**Windows 7***(vista should be similar)*: Open control panel in the "old view", click "Default programs", Click "Set a file type or protocol with a program"

For both you can sort the list by "current default/File type" and find Excel in the list. That will tell you all of the extensions that are associated.